# How do I display a message before closing the tkinter window?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

A message is required to be shown just before closing the tkinter window on the click of a close button added to the window.

```
lab = Label(window,text = 'thank you')
lab.grid()
window.destroy()
```

I used the above code to do so, but the window gets closed before the message is being displayed
Can I have the solution for this?

Comment: use `.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', your_func)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox


def display_msg():
    msgbox.showinfo(title='', message='Thank You')
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', display_msg)

root.mainloop()
```

which will show You a messagebox before closing,
or if You want to display a widget use this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label


def display_msg():
    msg = Label(root, text='Thank You!')
    msg.pack()
    root.after(3000, root.quit)


root = Tk()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', display_msg)

root.mainloop()
```

When You protocol root with 'WM_DELETE_WINDOM' You can make it execute a function when You try to close the window.

In the first example it will just show an infobox.

In the second example it will wait for 3 seconds (3000 miliseconds) and then destroy the root

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @sathvika also I updated the answer because I recently learned that it isn't that great to use `.update()` so I changed the code a bit to make it possible with `after()` which also makes it a bit more compact, so check the updated code (second example)

Comment: Can I have some clarifications regarding the following
1. What does the root.quit function do?
2. What is protocol function doing here?

Comment: @sathvika 1. as far as my understanding goes it quits the `mainloop()` process so basically closes everything. 2. also as far as I understand: it basically tells what to do in the case of that protocol becoming true, so in this case the protocol is `'WM_DELETE_WINDOW'` which is pretty self explanatory (but it is when (I think) one presses the `X` on the upper right corner of the screen), so this protocol will become sort of true when closing the window and thus will execute the given function

Comment: @sathvika  [here](https://www.pythonexample.org/gui/how-to-use-tkinters-protocol-handler-in-python/) is probably a better more in-depth explanation about protocols